# SQL constraints check <>

Tags: mysql, constraints, ddl

I just want to know what does the symbol <> after the keyword check do??

Example:

```
create table DistancesTbl(
   from varchar(100) not null,
   to varchar(100) not null,
   km smallint not null,
   primary key(from, to),
   constraint check_from_to check (from <> to),
   constraint check_distance check (km > 0)
);
```

In the previous query, what does the line
**constraint check_from_to check (from <> to),**
do exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another version of the [not equal operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal):

> ```
> Not equal:
> mysql> SELECT '.01' <> '0.01';
>        -> 1
> mysql> SELECT .01 <> '0.01';
>        -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 'zapp' <> 'zappp';
>        -> 1
> ```

It's the same as using `!=`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fell a bit ashamed for not knowing this actually! xD